# Is it the correct way to initialize array?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is one not-so-common way of initializing the array:

```
 int a[3] = {[2] 5, [0] 10, [1] 15};
```

Used this array in the program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //code
    int a[3] = {[2] 5, [0] 10, [1] 15};
    printf("a[0] = %d  a[1] = %d   a[2] = %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
a[0] = 10  a[1] = 15   a[2] = 5
```

**Online Compiler Link:**
http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/4onQAI

So, I have a question:

**Is it the correct way to initialize array?**

Comment: `printf("%d\n",,a[2]);` compiled?

Comment: No, this not a correct way to initialize an array. This is not valid C++.

Comment: @Sourav Yes, in gcc compiled successfully.

Comment: C and C++ are not teh same

Comment: I've never seen it before, so unless it is some obscure thing in one of the latest C++ versions...

Comment: @Sam, it also compiles using Intel C compiler.

Comment: @Sam Why? This worked successful in GCC compiler.

Comment: Interesting! What compiler have you used?

Comment: It works for gcc 4.8.4 and icc 16.0.3, but not for the c++ compilers (g++ and icpc)

Comment: Why would you want to initialize the array like that? What's the point?

Comment: It's a [compiler extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: Online GCC compiler : http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/4onQAI

Comment: @TartanLlama I thought designated initializers are part of standard C.... EDIT: ohh, i missed the missing `=`.

Comment: @User_Targaryen You may want to use that to initialize some of the elements of the array, but not all (for instance).

Comment: This is a GNU extension! The correct way of using it is int a[3] = { [2] = 5, [1] = 15, [2] = 5 }; You should be getting a warning about that with the appropriate flags.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. This does not work in C++ and is completely unrelated to Application Request Routing.

Comment: ICC accepts it because GCC accepts it. Doesn't make it correct though.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The question is tagged [C], not [C++]

Comment: @John3136 The question is tagged [C], not [C++]

Comment: @Kevin It was tagged C++ when I commented.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah sorry then, don't mind me :P

Comment: It is very clear that what OP is asking. Voted to reopen.

Comment: It's still a dupe though (which is what I used as a close reason, contrary to what the message suggests).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Close.  The correct way is as follows:

```
int a[3] = {[2] = 5, [0] = 10, [1] = 15};
```

This is a **designated initializer**, which allows you to initialize specified elements.  Any elements not specified are set to 0.

This is specified in section 6.7.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

The syntax you show is a non-standard extension supported by some compilers, specifically GCC.  If you were to compile with `-pedantic`, you would get the following warning:

> warning: obsolete use of designated initializer without ‘=’

Comment: C99 is not "the C standard". That is C11 with draft n1570. Please see the [foreword](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6)

Comment: @Olaf Updated link to point to the C11 document.

Comment: Thank you for giving answer...

Answer (score 11):

Your code snippet uses an obsolete syntax for this designated initializer:

```
int a[3] = {[2] = 5, [0] = 10, [1] = 15};
```

> An alternative syntax for this that has been obsolete since GCC 2.5 but GCC still accepts is to write ‘[index]’ before the element value, with no ‘=’. ([reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html))

Omitting `=` is not standard, and should not be used for new development.

Comment: no in upper question initialization of array is different.

Comment: @NectarM That's what the quoted part is talking about: "write ‘[index]’ before the element value, with no ‘=’"

Comment: why  and where this type of initialization we use?

Comment: @NectarM If you mean the old syntax, we shouldn't use it any longer. As for the new one, it's there to simplify initialization of sparsely populated arrays.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to use designated initializer is

```
int a[3] = {[2] = 5, [0] = 10, [1] = 15};
```

There should be `=` between the `[index]` and the value as per the C standard.
The way you are initialising may the some extension.

Grammer for initializations(C11-§6.7.9)

```
    initializer:
        assignment-expression
        { initializer-list }
        { initializer-list , }
    initializer-list:
        designationopt initializer
        initializer-list , designationopt initializer
    designation:
        designator-list =
    designator-list:
    designator
        designator-list designator
    designator:
        [ constant-expression ]
        . identifier
```